# How to get PHP to manipulate HTML code (copy/paste) before displaying the page

Tags: php

How to get PHP to manipulate HTML code (copy/paste) before sending to the browser.

I want to use PHP to get `html` code form inside `h1` and paste it in `h2`. On server. Before page is send over to the browser.

e.g ;

```
<h1> Some HTML CODE </h1>
<h2> <!-- EMPTY --> </h2>

<?php 
   // $var1 = HTML CODE from inside of h1
   // Paste in $var1 inside h2
   // Display The Page
?>
```

Comment: don't confuse client with serverside!

Comment: Copy & paste in what context? There is a dozen completely different ways to interpret this. Please be more specific

Comment: @Sascha Galley - I'm not confusing that! I looking for similar action, before page load - on server - using PHP.

Comment: @Pekka - I want PHP to find `h1` - get the html code from inside and paste it in `h2`.

Comment: sigh... I give up. Voting to close.

Comment: @pekka - Why is that? Exactly? PHP can generate HTML code so for sure can copy / paste code.

Comment: As said, there is a dozen ways to interpret this - you have HTML in the browser and want to manipulate it (not possible); you have a HTML document you're loading from elsewhere that you want to manipulate (possible using DOMDocument); you have a HTML page output that you want to filter before it is output (possible using DOMDocument and output buffering). As long as you don't clearly specify which one of these is your situation, you're wasting everybody's time with a lazily worded question.

Comment: @Pekka - see my edit. Does this make my the case clear enough?

Comment: @New yup, that's better - downvote removed. I'd suggest a change though: "After page is generated by PHP, but before it is output to the browser"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: manipulating DOM before outputting through browser:

```
<?php

$my_html = '<div>
        <h1>This is a h1</h1>
        <h2>This is a h2</h2>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($my_html);

$h1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0)->nodeValue;
var_dump($h1); // "This is a h1"

$dom->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->nodeValue = $h1;

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

This is just an example. Read up on [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)'s documentation.

---

Previous answer: You can't. PHP runs on the server side and javascript (thereby jQuery) on the client side. PHP doesn't know how to handle anything happening in the browser after the page has loaded.

Comment: I would like to to that before page is displayed. Get HTML code from one tag and paste-in different.

Comment: @NewUser: okay, I interpreted "copy" and "paste" as events triggered in the browser. I will refine my answer.

Comment: @NewUser: code edited, please try it out and see if that's what you mean :)

Comment: The following example does work. What does this mean:  `->saveHTML();` ?

Comment: @NewUser: it means that you get HTML back in form of a string instead of a `DOMDocument` object. It exports HTML for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some kind of fundamental misunderstanding how PHP (and JS) works. PHP creates the HTML page, it doesn't know how the browser will render it and it can't go "back" to the already rendered page to make changes. (Yes, I know it's possible, but not the same way JavaScript on a browser would do it.)

If you want to avoid coding the same thing twice you can use variables or functions. For example to have the same text in both `h1` and `h2`:

```
$content = "Hello World!";
echo "<h1>$content</h1>";
echo "<h2>$content</h2>";

// output: <h1>Hello World!</h1><h2>Hello World!</h2>
```

But if you want the page to change after it's been sent to the browser you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: I don't want it do alter the page after load. I'm looking for way of doing this before page is generated.

Comment: Ok. Variables and functions will do it then.

Comment: In your example you are using variable, where in real world example I want to get `h1` content (coming form DB) and after this copy this text/html code over to `h2`.

Comment: Right. Put the DB content in a variable and print the variable both in the `<h1>` and `<h2>`. Or do you have HTML in the database?

Comment: Mostly HTML code, which is being altered by separate function (WYSIWYG editor).